# Roadmap for a Xtext DSL query-language

Tags: eclipse, xtext

im new to programming bigger software than single classes.
During a project it's my task to implement a variation of sql to query a cassandra database. 
I already have defined my grammar in Xtext but im not sure how to use it now.

I miss more or less the whole roadmap on what to do now to use my grammar and access the database.
Has someone done something similar and can tell me what to do?

Comment: can you please some more context: shall the dsl be executed directly from the dsl or live from the editor. so you should think about generation vs interpretation

Comment: Hello Christian,
I think we want to use the editor. Unfortunately my colleagues were not able to give an exact answer. 
So far we only know that we get queries and how to use them to access the database is our turn.

Comment: have a look at https://www.dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu.html in your case you wont call the generator but turn the model into something you can execute on the db server

Comment: it seems to be a good start thank you!
If im right i have to get the user input from the modelfile and build a string out of it.
But i think its more useful to store the nodes of the ast in a stringbuilder so i can iterate over it to devide the queryparts that Cassandra can interpred and the parts that i have to use afterwards to postprocess the cassandra output.
Do you also have a example for that?

Comment: am not sure that you mean. xtext resources offer you access to the ast and node model (text). your model is at resource.getContents().get(0)

Comment: I think i wasnt clear enough but you actually answered my question.
Ty for your help!